# How to convert string of array to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm getting and object from an api that looks like this -

`data = {
   ...
   filter: "[1,2,3]"
   ...
}`

Now, i want to take that string of array and convert it to array of numbers, that is [1,2,3].

Thanks a lot

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on your field:

```js
const data = {
   filter: "[1,2,3]"
}

data.filter = JSON.parse(data.filter);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: yes it works that way tnx; but strange thing, if you do the same thing just with array of strings insteaf of numbers it doesnt work ...